# ActiveRecord defineAttributes()

Tags: plugin-development

I have just started to build my first plugin with Craft CMS.

Im at the part where I want to defne my database table.

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/plugins/database

For the method definedAttributes() what values will the array accept.

It looks like I can define values and types, but how do i add field lengths, primarykeys etc..

Are there some other docs that I can look at?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You best bet would be to start by knowing all the exisiting default attribute types in this file:

`craft/app/enums/AttributeType.php`

Then look in

`craft/app/helpers/ModelHelper.php`
and
`craft/app/helpers/DbHelper.php`

There you will find all sorts of properties for column types and their default configs options like maxLength. Here is all the ColumnTypes defaults:

```
public static $attributeTypeDefaults = array(
    AttributeType::Mixed      => array('model' => null, 'column' => ColumnType::Text),
    AttributeType::Bool       => array('maxLength' => 1, 'default' => false, 'required' => true, 'column' => ColumnType::TinyInt, 'unsigned' => true),
    AttributeType::ClassName  => array('maxLength' => 150, 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
    AttributeType::DateTime   => array('column' => ColumnType::DateTime),
    AttributeType::Email      => array('minLength' => 5, 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
    AttributeType::Enum       => array('values' => array(), 'column' => ColumnType::Enum),
    AttributeType::Handle     => array('maxLength' => 255, 'reservedWords' => 'id,dateCreated,dateUpdated,uid,title', 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
    AttributeType::Locale     => array('column' => ColumnType::Locale),
    AttributeType::Name       => array('maxLength' => 255, 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
    AttributeType::Number     => array('min' => null, 'max' => null, 'decimals' => 0),
    AttributeType::SortOrder  => array('column' => ColumnType::TinyInt),
    AttributeType::Template   => array('maxLength' => 500, 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
    AttributeType::Url        => array('maxLength' => 255, 'column' => ColumnType::Varchar),
);
```

You will also see in the DbHelper.php how the column types map into the mysql definition of the table like so:

```
case ColumnType::Decimal:
            {
                $def = 'DECIMAL('.$config['length'].','.$config['decimals'].')';
                break;
            }
```

Hope that helps. I would encourage you to look at all the `defineAttributes()` methods in the `craft/app/records` directory.

Comment: Thanks Luke thats a big help, how do I get my PK field to auto increament? I have noticed that a uid field gets added how is this used?

Comment: No worries. I suppose it should be documented better but most of the defaults are fine anyway so just using the default attribute types is fine.

Comment: PK id already auto increments by default you don't need to add id to defineAttributes it gets added by craft on install.

Comment: @GaryConstable Craft adds and uses the uid column internally. No need to worry about it.

Comment: I'm late to the party, but I'm also working through validation/records etc. I found [this article](https://experiencehq.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-validation-in-craft-part-2-attributetypes) to be quite helpful as well.

Comment: For further reference, here's a list of all the possible `AttributeType::*` constants (the above list from `ModelHelper.php` doesn't include all the possibilities): https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/enums/AttributeType.php