# FeedMe import to update specific Matrix blocks without affecting others

Tags: matrix, plugin-feedme, updates

I'm familiar with [using FeedMe to import into Matrix blocks](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/guides/importing-into-matrix.html), but I’m not sure how to do the following:

- I have a series of existing entries, each with a series of existing Matrix blocks of several types
- I need to update one field of one block type *without affecting the others already in the Matrix field.*

I've just done a test of what I hoped might work, being careful to make sure that `Don’t import` was the setting for *all other fields* across the entire entry scope.

*But it wiped out the other existing blocks.* (I had a backup!)

I’ve generated a report to acquire the `block.id` of the specific blocks I need to update but I'm not sure where to go from here.

There doesn't seem to be a way to use FeedMe to update blocks directly?

Do I need to resort to some kind of SQL?

---

Note: it's not going to be practical to acquire all the existing block data and incorporate that into the import. Or at least, I'd rather not!

---

### Update

It appears this issue is an intrinsic part of the [Matrix content gets overwritten on import #463](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/463) 2019 thread and there is no answer as yet?

> “Feed Me doesn’t have a way of matching your feed’s blocks with existing entry blocks, so it will always just delete the current entry blocks and recreate them with whatever’s in the feed.”

FWIW I think [Eli](https://github.com/craftcms/feed-me/issues/463#issuecomment-998953478) describes it fairly with…

> “Whether or not this is ‘expected’ from a programmatic standpoint, it's definitely not what I would expect as a user – even one who is pretty familiar with Craft's internals.”

Hope this can be overcome in a future release.

---

### Update 2

Just had a look at the DB and, as I know the block IDs, it looks promising that I can do an SQL UPDATE on the `matrixcontent_myfieldhandle` table, but as the field to be updated is an Entries field it could get complicated!

---

### Update 3

Because my field is an `Entries` field it looks like I need to SQL INSERT into the `relations` table, which looks straightforward enough, as long as I can play nicely with [values for the UID column](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/6927/3507). Wonder if batch generation with [uuidtools.com/generate/bulk](https://www.uuidtools.com/generate/bulk) is compliant?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to update the Matrix block using the PHP APIs, rather than editing DB values directly.

You can do that like so:

```php
use Craft;
use craft\elements\MatrixBlock;

$block = MatrixBlock::find()
    ->id($blockId)
    ->fieldId($matrixFieldId)
    ->one();

$block->setFieldValue('fieldHandle', $newValue);
// ...

Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($block);
```

(Note that setting the `fieldId` param on the Matrix block query is necessary. Oterwise the block won’t be queried with any of its content.)

Comment: Thanks Brandon. That sounds helpful. Had just got to the point where my attempts at INSERT INTO `relations` were not working. (I guess there are joins of some sort I don't know about which I am not making.) So I'll give your suggestion a go :)